# Allow sudo in default guest account

Tags: wine, sudo, playonlinux, guest-session, apparmor

I am trying to run Microsoft Office for some public workstations.

I have added the following entry to my sudoers file:
`%win ALL=(windows) NOPASSWD: /usr/share/playonlinux/ /home/windows/.PlayOnLinux`

And this to my prefs.sh (for the default guest):
`usermod -aG win $USER`

If I stop/teardown apparmor, I can run my windows applications within the guest using `sudo -u windows -i`, however I do not want to leave apparmor disabled. **How can I configure apparmor to allow me to change gid from the guest account?**

*I realize that this is a security risk, however the windows user does not have any special privileges, and I still get some protection over a static guest from wiping the guest account after logout*

Comment: The guest account is designed to be secured by apparmor and unless you want to start allowing the guest sudo access and re-writing apparmor profiles, I highly suggest you use a regular account (rather then guest) without sudo access.

Comment: The guest account is designed to be both temporary and confined.

Comment: You might want to have a look at overlayfs and reflinked directories. Each user should have a completely separate home directory with their own wine prefix.

Comment: It's an interesting challenge. I have a few ideas that I'll try out during the weekend if I get time. They should work very well, but I'll have to read up on how guest accounts are made in newer versions.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: I agree this sounds interesting. The [CustomizeGuestSession tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) might be helpful when you give it a shot.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Thanks. Yes, what I'm thinking, is that it might be possible to simply add a --reflink=auto to the skel-part of /usr/sbin/guest-account. Then, if you're using btrfs, you'll just get a CoW-ed copy of /etc/guest-session/skel. So in this case, you'd get a clean PlayOnLinux environment at each login. Should actually be even faster than it is today because of --reflink. But I want to test it before I recommend it. It's also possible that it might be better to use an overlayfs because that wouldn't require btrfs. But I'm not that familiar with overlayfs yet.